# What libraries / approach should I have for connecting with ruby on rails system to a standard Microsoft Web service using the soap protocol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, heroku, webservice-client

I am looking to connect with an API (documentation: http://carsolize.com/carsolize_API_v2.5.pdf).

To get started in a good direction how would you do this? (What gems/methods would I use?, any tips highly appreciated!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using Savon: https://github.com/savonrb/savon it helps you create SOAP request neatly. Check out the documentation [here](http://savonrb.com/).